# Iterated substitution in Haskell via the Identity Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

As far as I can tell, one of the big uses of the monadic bind operation is to do variable substitution such as

```
do x <- maybeComputeSomething
   y <- maybeComputeSomethingElse
   maybeDoStuff x y
```

This is all well and good if maybeComputeSomething, maybeComputeSomethingElse, and maybeDoStuff all return Maybe values, but I feel like this form of iterated substitution would be useful in computations even if there wasn't the possibility of a returned Nothing. Since the identity is a monad, I would in some sense expect to be able to do something such as

```
do x <- computeSomething
   y <- computeSomethingElse
   doStuff x y
```

which would expand to something looking like

```
computeSomething >>= (\x -> 
    computeSomethingElse >>= (\y ->
        doStuff x y))
```

and since bind in the identity monad is simply x >>= f = f x, this would act as

```
doStuff computeSomething computeSomethingElse
```

if >>= were treated as the identity monad's bind, but this (unsurprisingly) fails, because after all I never explicitly stated a monad (unlike the Maybe example when the types are clearly of the form Maybe a) and if Haskell assumed the identity monad everywhere the majority of cases would get cluttered up quite fast by the required disambiguations.

So this leads me to my question. I want some code that feels like

```
do x <- computeSomething
   y <- computeSomethingElse
   doStuff x y
```

and that does the same thing as

```
doStuff computeSomething computeSomthingElse
```

I understand that I could do this by explicitly defining an Id monad which looks like Maybe except without the Nothing possibility, but this takes types a -> Id a, and so doesn't really define the identity monad. Furthermore, my functions now have to have types a -> Id b, whereas I would really like them to still be of the form a -> b. Is there a way to create the repeated substitution feel without introducing complexity in the types involved?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what's wrong with just `let x = computeSomething; y = computeSomethingElse in doStuff x y`?

Comment: Really not much, only that it breaks symmetry with other code, but if that's necessary then it's necessary. I was more wondering whether it's necessary. Also, if I bind to the same variable more than once it looks weird semantically to write

   `let x = computeSomething; x = workWith x in workMoreWith x`

although I guess that would work?

Comment: Actually I tested the code `let a = 1; a = a+1 in a` and it didn't compile, which doesn't make sense to me since it should seem to expand to `(\a -> (\a -> a) a+1) 1`, which is fine, but the code `do a <- Just 1; a <- Just (a+1); Just (a+1)` gives `Just 3`, as expected, since that is actually `Just 1 >>= (\a -> Just (a+1) >>= (\a -> Just (a+1)))`. This is a pretty big advantage which comes from the fact that the bind operator separates the lambda expressions enough to allow for reuse of the variable name.

Comment: Brian: let in haskell is 'let rec' a la scheme. so the `a` is the one you are defining. `let a = a + 1` will blow up for most numerical types. but consider `let ones = 1 : ones in ones` which uses the same construction, and generates an infinite list by referencing itself. To implement your example, you'd need to alpha rename the second variable: `let a = 1; a' = a + 1 in a'` or just `b where b = a + 1; a + 1`. There is no "non-capturing variable binding" let (a la scheme/ml's let) in Haskell. With Haskell 2010 you can exploit pattern guards to get some semblance of this, but I'm out of room.

Comment: er, typo `b where b = a + 1; a = 1`

Comment: Brian, I don't think you should use a monad for this, because it's unnecessary. Other Haskell programmers will be wondering why you did, beginners will complain, your code will be longer unnecessarily, and you will introduce an unnecessary visual/syntactic ordering upon the code (although the code's semantics should be equivalent to the let... or ...where forms which are recommended for this situation).

Comment: Also, reuse of variable names within the same scope is generally frowned upon in Haskell, because it is an easy opportunity for bugs to creep in. I know it can be annoying to have to use foo1 or foo' instead of foo, but it's probably safer (and safer still to refactor your code so you don't need such extra names).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly the identity monad needs at least a newtype wrapper to dispatch upon.

The reason makes sense when you consider overlapping instances. A monad instance that was somehow constructed for

```
type Id a = a
```

would always apply, subsuming any of the more interesting monads.

Therefore you have to implement it as something like

```
newtype Id a = Id a
```

Then

```
instance Monad Id where
    return = Id
    Id a >>= f = f a
```

This gives a sufficient hint to the type system to know when you really want to work with this monad. Note: This is an artifact of typeclass dispatch. In languages that offer ML-like modules or Scala, where you don't have typeclass inference to help (and conversely to worry about) you can define a true identity monad, but then you are forced to route all calls to that particular >>= by yourself, so it turn to be a wash or a net loss anyways.

Now you can

```
do x <- computeSomething
   y <- computeSomethingElse
   doStuff x y
```

but the types are

```
computeSomething :: Id a
computeSomethingElse :: Id b
doStuff :: a -> b -> Id c
```

and if you made Id into an instance of Applicative the syntax could reduce to

```
doStuff <$> computeSoemthing <*> computeSomethingElse
```

so each of those methods would have to explicitly apply the Id newtype wrapper or wrap their result in return.

In practice it is better to use let bindings in this context.

```
let
   x = computeSomething
   y = computeSomethingElse
in doStuff x y
```

or more idiomatically, a where clause

```
doStuff x y where
  x = computeSomething
  y = computeSomethingElse
```

or even in this case, since those are so small, and to come full circle to the Applicative example above:

```
doStuff computeSomething computeSomethingElse
```

Comment: +1 for the idiomatic `let` thing. Introducing new variables in functional calculus is always a lambda abstraction of some form (`x <- foo` actually involves a lambda too).

Answer (score 1):

Note this is really a comment, but I've made it an answer to allow formatting...

It looks like you just want a function similar to **liftM2**, except the *post-combine* operation is monadic rather than pure - e.g.

```
monady2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
```

Compare with liftM2 where the post-combiner (the first argument) is pure:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
```

The **monady2** combinator doesn't exist in the standard libraries, but you are free to define it.

Comment: this is very similar to Applicative style, albeit with some `join`s included.